# Как добавить затухающий градиент внизу блока?

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

Всем привет. Не понимаю как сделать такую прозрачность снизу у блока с прокруткой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MaximLensky сверстать блок я могу, я не знаю как сделать прозрачность снизу. Вопрос состоит в этом.

Comment: https://cssgradient.io/

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.grid::after{
 background: linear-gradient(transparent, black);
 height: 40px;
 position: relative;
 top: -40px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Вместо .grid подставь класс своего блока.